# Insert data in ssrs table in the query

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I would like to insert some data in the ssrs table.
I would like to show it like this here:

[image]

How can I add these data in my query in SSRS. I have no possibility to change something in the database.

```
       | P1|P2 |P3 |P4 |P5 |P6 |P7 |P8
Group A|84%|87%|81%|81%|79%|96%|86%|88%
Group B|66%|22%|79%|64%|53%|94%|5% |23%
```

The Problem is:
Last week on wednesday the database did not recorded the data from Group A and Group B. And I have no possibility to correct/add the missing data in the database. And thats why I would like to add these missed data in my query and show it in the report.

My query:

```
SELECT *
    FROM (
    Select 

intervaldate as Datum
,tsystem.Name as Name
,team as group
,SUM(GoodUnits) As Goods
,SUM(TheoreticalUnits) As Units
from tCount inner join tsystem ON tCount.systemid = tsystem.id

where IntervalDate >= @StartDateTime AND IntervalDate <= @EndDateTime
    group by intervaldate
    ) c
    inner join
    (
    SELECT 
    sh.Date as Datum,
    sc.Name as Name
    FROM tHistory sh
    INNER JOIN tSchedule sc ON (sc.ID = sh.ScheduleID)
    WHERE Scheduled != 0
    ) p ON p.Name = c.Name
```

When I realized that the data was not recorded I did written down the data on paper.

Comment: Well.... where is the data? does it exist anywhere? Do you need to transform existing data or do you need to create data from thin air? Both are possible but you need to explain what you're talking about.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid:I updated my question

Comment: 1. Open SQL Server Management Studio; 2. Paste in your query and confirm it works; 3.In another window, generate your required data using the `VALUES` constructor https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776382.aspx; 4. Use `UNION ALL` to join your generated data to your original query.

Comment: For step 3 above type this and run it: `SELECT *
FROM (
VALUES 
('Group 1',0.84,0.87,0.81,0.91),
('Group 2',0.66,0.22,0.79,0.64)
) AS ExtraData([Group],P1,P2,P3,P4);`

Comment: You need to fill in the rest and UNION ALL it. If you like this solution I will explain it properly as an answer

Comment: thank you, yes it will be really helpful if you can explain it in detail

Comment: I just checked your query - it has no correlation with the dataset you posted. Your query appears to return a date, a name (string) and two numbers, and I guess many rows. Your sample data has no dates and 9 columns. How do these datasets fit together?

Comment: Yes your right I forgot to put the group here in my question, I will correct it. And with the two numbers I do a calculation in ssrs like: Sum(Fields!Goods.Value)/Sum(Fields!Units.Valu)*100

Comment: The group consists of 3 grops: A,B and C. And name consist of 8 persons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add manual data to your posted query, you can use `UNION ALL` and `VALUES` like so:

First make sure you get your 'additional data' correct on its own. Try this example:

```
SELECT Datum,Name,[Group],Goods,Units
FROM (
VALUES 
(CAST('2015-01-01' AS DATE),'AName','A',10.32,20.76),
(CAST('2015-01-01' AS DATE),'AName','B',12.72,16.15)
) AS ExtraData(Datum,Name,[Group],Goods,Units);
```

I am making many assumptions here as you have not provided enough info in your question.

Anyway if that is correct, then you simply attach it to your original data with `UNION ALL`

```
SELECT Datum,Name,[Group],Goods,Units
    FROM (
    Select 
intervaldate as Datum
,tsystem.Name as Name
,team as [Group]
,SUM(GoodUnits) As Goods
,SUM(TheoreticalUnits) As Units
from tCount inner join tsystem ON tCount.systemid = tsystem.id
where IntervalDate >= @StartDateTime AND IntervalDate <= @EndDateTime
    group by intervaldate
    ) c
    inner join
    (
    SELECT 
    sh.Date as Datum,
    sc.Name as Name
    FROM tHistory sh
    INNER JOIN tSchedule sc ON (sc.ID = sh.ScheduleID)
    WHERE Scheduled != 0
    ) p ON p.Name = c.Name
/* Original query ends. Now add more data */
UNION ALL
SELECT Datum,Name,[Group],Goods,Units
FROM (
VALUES 
(CAST('2015-01-01' AS DATE),'AName','A',10.32,20.76),
(CAST('2015-01-01' AS DATE),'AName','B',12.72,16.15)
) AS ExtraData(Datum,Name,[Group],Goods,Units);
```

Comment: Thank you, that was really helpful