# visibility of Data in SSRS

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

This is a follow on from this question:

[Insert data in ssrs table in the query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38630652/insert-data-in-ssrs-table-in-the-query/38634014#38634014)

I added in my table manually some data and I created a report in SSRS:

[image]

part of the Query:

```
UNION ALL
    SELECT *
    FROM  (Values 
    (Cast('2016-07-25 00:00:00.000' AS DATE),71.9,'Team A','Nacht',73.0, 'M101', '',0.0),    
(Cast('2016-07-25 00:00:00.000' AS DATE),71.9,'Team B','Früh',71.0, 'M105', '',84.5)
     )
    AS ExtraData([Datum],[OEETag],[Team],[Schicht],[OEETeam],[Name],[Product],[SystemOEE])
```

The Problem now is that the manual data displays in every table. How can I set the visibility? I would like to diplays the manual data only on 25.07.2016. I used in my query parameters: @StartDateTime and @EndDateTime

In the visibility settings I tried it with this expression:

```
=iif(Parameters!StartDateTime.Value="2016-07-25 00:00:00.000", False, iif(Parameters!EndDateTime.Value="2016-07-25 00:00:00.000", False, True))
```

But not really working.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: It looks correct. Try converting the text date to a date - `CDATE("2016-07-25")` in the SSRS expression to see if that helps.

Comment: there is no error, only if I choose a period from 2016-07-20 to 2016-07-28 then the date 2016-07-25 not appears in the report

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select *
from(
    SELECT *
    FROM  (Values 
    (Cast('2016-07-25 00:00:00.000' AS DATE),71.9,'Team A','Nacht',73.0, 'M101', '',0.0),    
(Cast('2016-07-25 00:00:00.000' AS DATE),71.9,'Team B','Früh',71.0, 'M105', '',84.5)
     )
    AS ExtraData([Datum],[OEETag],[Team],[Schicht],[OEETeam],[Name],[Product],[SystemOEE])

) as source
where Datum = @startDate
```

this is not complete solution but this will let you filter on your datum column based on your parameter.

Comment: Thank you, that´s it. I used this expression: `Datum >= @StartDateTime AND Datum <= @EndDateTime`